How can we configure ArgoCD Application to install from a github release downloads url?
A case in point - kube-blocks crds. We are supposed to install them directly from https://github.com/apecloud/kubeblocks/releases/download/v0.9.0/kubeblocks_crds.yaml.
If I do not want to download them and store in my local repo, is it possible to configure the Application object to download and install these CRDS from that url directly?
There is already an existing issue here - https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/discussions/6603. It hints at the possibility to do it using kustomize, but it is unclear to me how exactly and the aforementioned discussion does not provide any details.

The link you provided does contain a Kustomize example to achieve what you want. Do you maybe have a more specific question?

The problem is that I still have to create a local repository with the kustomization code and feed it into ArgoCD. At the end of the day, ArgoCD downloads from my local repo and then runs kustomize to download the resource. I was wondering if there is a way to spare the need for a local repo and let ArgoCD download it all.

Oh okay. Then no, ArgoCD sources are: Git repo, Helm repo, maybe OCI registries. But what's the issue in having a local Git repo? The idea is that you should have one to store your ArgoCD Application manifests anyway.

I have an App-Of-Apps HELM chart in the ArgoCD management repo. It scans staging repos, which can contain either ArgoCD Application objects or HELM charts or plain manifests. The first option requires more know-how from the feature team. Most use the second option - HELM chart. But I can also deploy a 3rd party HELM chart using the same technique. The problem is that I cannot deploy 3rd party plain yamls if they are not in the repo, but in the releases pages.

What you could do is also support Kustomize then, it's almost like plain manifests for ArgoCD: if there's a kustomization.yaml file in the folder it will consider it's Kustomize that is used (https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/kustomize/).

Yes, that is how the current logic works. I have a local repo with kustomization file that downloads the CRDs from the github release page. Compare it with the case where CRDs are downloaded directly from the github repo. If they live in a dedicated folder, then ArgoCD could be pointed at them directly. No need for a local repo. But because  ArgoCD does not know to download arbitrary url, we cannot use this direct approach when the same CRDs are to be downloaded from the releases page, not the repo.
